# SQL To Get New User Acquisition

Tags: sql

I'm creating a new user acquisition report for my system, specifically targeting users who have never logged in before. The query below successfully covers a 4-day period (from `2023-11-13` to `2023-11-16`), but I'm looking to expand this to a 30-day timeframe.

```
SELECT '2023-11-13' AS event_date, COUNT(DISTINCT USER_ID) AS new_user_acquisition
FROM EVENTS
WHERE EVENT_DATE = '2023-11-13'

UNION ALL

SELECT '2023-11-14' AS event_date, COUNT(DISTINCT USER_ID) AS new_user_acquisition
FROM EVENTS
WHERE EVENT_DATE = '2023-11-14'
  AND USER_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT USER_ID
    FROM EVENTS
    WHERE EVENT_DATE = '2023-11-13'
  )

UNION ALL

SELECT '2023-11-15' AS event_date, COUNT(DISTINCT USER_ID) AS new_user_acquisition
FROM EVENTS
WHERE EVENT_DATE = '2023-11-15'
  AND USER_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT USER_ID
    FROM EVENTS
    WHERE EVENT_DATE IN ('2023-11-13', '2023-11-14')
  )

UNION ALL

SELECT '2023-11-16' AS event_date, COUNT(DISTINCT USER_ID) AS new_user_acquisition
FROM EVENTS
WHERE EVENT_DATE = '2023-11-16'
  AND USER_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT USER_ID
    FROM EVENTS
    WHERE EVENT_DATE IN ('2023-11-13', '2023-11-14', '2023-11-15')
  );
```

Is there a more efficient way to structure my query without listing each day individually and excluding the others?

I want to avoid the tedious process of manually specifying each date while ensuring the report accurately captures new users who haven't logged in previously.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? (postgres, sql server, oracle, snowflake, mysql, etc)?

Comment: To be clear, what is the **exact datatype** defined in the database for the `event_type` column?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```sql
WITH UserLoginStatus AS (
  SELECT
    USER_ID,
    EVENT_DATE,
    LAG(EVENT_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY USER_ID ORDER BY EVENT_DATE) AS previous_login_date
  FROM EVENTS
  WHERE EVENT_DATE BETWEEN '2023-10-15' AND '2023-11-15'
)

SELECT
  EVENT_DATE,
  COUNT(DISTINCT USER_ID) AS new_user_acquisition
FROM UserLoginStatus
WHERE previous_login_date IS NULL
GROUP BY EVENT_DATE
ORDER BY EVENT_DATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce this whole problem into a couple of aggregations. First determine the date that you first saw each `user_id` using `min(event_date)`, and then just count the number of `user_id` that share each date:

```
SELECT first_date, COUNT(user_id)
FROM 
  (
     SELECT user_id, MIN(event_date) as first_date
     FROM EVENT_DATE
     GROUP BY user_id
  ) dt
GROUP BY first_date
```

That will give you the count of new users for every date where a new user is found in your table. You can toss a `WHERE` clause on that subquery to constrain it to just the last 30 days like `WHERE event_date >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '30' DAY` or whatever syntax is appropriate for your RDBMS.

[Here is a dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TtzwM23k) of this in action.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do it

```
WITH mydata
AS (
    SELECT min(event_date) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) first_date
        ,user_id
        ,event_date
    FROM EVENTS
    WHERE event_date BETWEEN '2023-11-13'
            AND DATEADD(day, 30, '2023-11-13')
    )
SELECT count(DISTINCT user_id)
    ,event_date
FROM mydata
WHERE first_date = event_date
group by event_date
```